# How to split multiple json data results

Tags: c#, json

I got following json string from response from server that looks like this:

```
{
  "resultCount": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "apartmentNo": "",
      "city": "BEOGRAD",
      "floor": "",
      "houseNo": "99",
      "houseNo2": "",
      "phoneNo": "011\/000-0000",
      "postalCode": "11000",
      "region": "SOME REGION",
      "street": "SOME STREET",
      "firstName": "FNAME",
      "lastName": "LNAME"
    },
    {
      "apartmentNo": "",
      "city": "BEOGRAD",
      "floor": "",
      "houseNo": "99",
      "houseNo2": "",
      "phoneNo": "011\/000-0000",
      "postalCode": "11000",
      "region": "SOME REGION",
      "street": "SOME STREET",
      "firstName": "FNAME",
      "lastName": "LNAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

As it can be seen, there is two results in json response that belongs to "result" and it is separated like {...first...},{...second...}. I already know how to handle only one result, but how should I handle two or more results like this json example?

I want to add this data to data grid view to show result to user.

My code to parse a single result is:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseText);
string ime = o["results"]["firstName"].ToString();
string prezime = o["results"]["lastName"].ToString();
string adresa = o["results"]["street"].ToString() + " " + o["results"]["houseNo"].ToString();
string mesto = o["results"]["city"].ToString();
string pbroj = o["results"]["postalCode"].ToString();
string tel = o["results"]["phoneNo"].ToString();

dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ime, prezime, adresa, mesto, pbroj, tel);
```

I also found a method around here to literate trought all childs using jtokens but there must be a better way of parsing these in etc. multiple arrays, I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `o.Value<List<JObject>>("results")` ?

Comment: It might be easier to cast this to a strongly typed object and then using the Newtonsoft Json library to deserialize into the model. Having a strongly typed model also helps you bind to grids a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use a `POO`/Models  like the following

```
public class Result
{
    public string apartmentNo { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string floor { get; set; }
    public string houseNo { get; set; }
    public string houseNo2 { get; set; }
    public string phoneNo { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int resultCount { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

and parse it like this

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("your json here ");
```

Comment: me too ! what he said :P

Comment: Works like a charm, I used foreach loop to literate trough list and added result from created class. Thank you very much it realy helped me out, wish you the best.